# Filter Sonar issue introduces due to my code changes

Tags: sonarqube

I want to filter the sonar issue introduces by my code changes. Is it possible to filter it from Sonar Qube after the code checked-in into repository. Is there a  way? But i know we can do before check in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As issues are, by default, assigned to the last committer of the line, you can simply use the assignee filter in issues page. Example: https://sonarqube.com/component_issues/index?id=org.sonarsource.ldap%3Asonar-ldap#resolved=false|assignees=simonbrandhof%40github

Comment: but in my case, its not assigning .Can you tell me how it will be assigned by default

Comment: A SCM plugin must be installed, for example Git or Subversion. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment